# How do i organize flex items properly?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

The issue I am facing is not that big of a problem but it could potentially ruin the look of my page. The problem is I have a div `card` that is a flex object i.e it's parent div has its display set to flex

```css
.season-list{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<div class="season-list container">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="image" src="some.jpg" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <small>Some text</small><br>
        <small>something else</small>
        <br>
        <small class="tempt">something;</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now what happens is that setting `justify-content` as `space-evenly` does organize the card object properly i.e three in a row, however, when i have lets say 7 cards, it organizes the first three normally but ends up aligning the last card in the bottom-centre of the previous row. I have tried messing around with different justify-content values but to no avail. Like i said this is not a big problem but could make the page look a little less pleasing to the eye.

Comment: Do you want to align the last row to left? Honestly, I didn't understand your issue.

Comment: Please create a [mcve] and share an image of desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch to the grid display to avoid this :

example with a card of 250px (update this value to your needs)

```css
.season-list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 200px);
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  gap: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="season-list container">
  <div class="card ">
    <img class="image " src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/200/100" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <small>Some text</small><br>
        <small>something else</small>
        <br>
        <small class="tempt">something;</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card ">
    <img class="image " src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/200/100" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <small>Some text</small><br>
        <small>something else</small>
        <br>
        <small class="tempt">something;</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="card ">
    <img class="image " src="https://picsum.photos/id/1011/200/100" alt="">
    <div class="overlay">
      <div class="text">
        <small>Some text</small><br>
        <small>something else</small>
        <br>
        <small class="tempt">something;</small>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Play in full screen to check its behavior or play with the codepen : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/BapgbYx *(added a few examples borders to the card and grid-auto-rows to set each rows the same height.)*

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9cix.png)

I think this is exactly what you're looking for

```css
.season-list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.card {
  background-color: rgb(247, 56, 56);
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  width: 10rem;
  height: 10rem;
  margin: 3rem;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```